# Increasing the number of iterations make the result of a polymorphic "encryption" slightly different

Tags: python, python-3.x, obfuscation

For a random project, I'm writing a python program that randomly generates "encryption" and "decryption" routines for strings. The resulting routines are mean to be used in `eval()`

```
def buildRoutines(routine_len):
    instructions = ['+', '-', '^']
    pairs = {'+': '-', '-': '+', '^': '^'}
    encrypt = ""
    decrypt = ""
    random.seed()
    for _ in range(0, routine_len):
        i = random.randrange(3)
        j = random.randrange(100)
        encrypt += 'e=' + 'chr((' + 'ord(e)' + instructions[i] + str(j) + ')%255)' + ';'
        decrypt  = 'e=' + 'chr((' + 'ord(e)' + pairs[instructions[i]] + str(j) + ')%255)' + ';' + decrypt
    # Do some more stuff
    encrypt = 'a="";e=""\nfor b in c:e=b;' + encrypt + 'a+=e;'
    decrypt = 'd="";e=""\nfor b in a:e=b;' + decrypt + 'd+=e;'
    return {'encrypt': encrypt, 'decrypt': decrypt}
```

Up to around 50-ish iterations works fine (routine_len), but when I go above that, the result is slightly off the original string. The more iterations, the more different it is. At 150 iterations, just one or two characters are wrong.

I've been trying to figure this out, but I can't seem to fix it. It's just probably something really stupid that I'm missing.

EDIT: The value I was using to mod was wrong. Thank you everyone who replied.

Comment: if it's wrong, it's wrong regardless of the number of 'iterations'

Comment: @MitchWheat I would assume that, but with 100-ish and under iterations, the string looks exactly the same as the original string. How can it be wrong then? When I check the equality of the result with the original string, (with ==) it returns True when they look the same and false when they don't. Therefore, the routines don't work *sometimes* at higher lengths.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `%256` and the reason why you running into issues for high iterations is that you're missing that edge case? `%255` means that your max value is 254.

Comment: @MitchWheat And you were right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `%255`, your max value isn't 255, it's 254. Use `%256` instead.

Comment: That was it! Thanks,